# repetitive arithmetic in Python

Tags: python

From a purely performance standpoint, is it generally the best practice to assign the result of a repetitive arithmetic operation to a variable and use that variable throughout the code? Or does Python have some internal way of caching the result and using it whenever it encounters the repeated statement.

For example is this more efficient:

```
a = 50
b = a*12-1
c = a*b

print c
#some code
print c*100 + 10
#some code
print c/100 + 20
#etc
```

Than this:

```
print 50*(50*12-1)
#some code
print 50*(50*12-1) * 100 + 10
#some code
print 50*(50*12-1) / 100 + 20
#etc
```

Comment: Are you talking about repetitive expressions that involve only literals (i.e. inherently constant values), like your example above?

Comment: If it makes your code more readable to use more variables and doesn't create a noticeable difference using benchmarks, then use code that's more readable. Unless you're doing really complex calculations, you probably can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem likes a pretty negligible speed up to me:

```
> python -m timeit 'a = 50; b = a*12-1; c = a*b; c; c*100+10; c/100+20;'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.27 usec per loop
> python -m timeit '50*(50*12-1); 50*(50*12-1) * 100 + 10; 50*(50*12-1) / 100 + 20'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.218 usec per loop
```

Assignment is marginally slower than continually recalculating, but as korylprince states in the comments, assignment will lead to easier to read code.

edit: I think this is what gnibbler meant in the comments, but it is slower still:

```
> python -m timeit 'def x(): a = 50; b = a*12-1; c = a*b; c; c*100+10; c/100+20;' 'x()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.428 usec per loop
```

edit2: This is actually what gnibbler meant in the comments, and the difference is still negligle. The comments about using more readable one still hold:

```
> python -m timeit -s 'def x(): a = 50; b = a*12-1; c = a*b; c; c*100+10; c/100+20;' 'x()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.367 usec per loop
> python -m timeit -s 'def x(): 50*(50*12-1); 50*(50*12-1) * 100 + 10; 50*(50*12-1) / 100 + 20' 'x()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.278 usec per loop
```

Comment: global lookups are slower. You should try this inside a function.

Comment: Sort of. You missed the `-s` for the function definition. I meant you to also run the literal only version in a function to get a meaningful comparison. The reason it appears slower is that you're now adding in a function overhead. But since this stuff is normally going to be done inside a function, you need to make sure you're benchmarking the variable lookups inside the functions.

Comment: If you use `dis.dis(x)` you can see that the peephole optimiser is reducing all the math to constants in `def x(): 50*(50*12-1); 50*(50*12-1) * 100 + 10; 50*(50*12-1) / 100 + 20` (in python3.3 at least)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of any Python implementation that caches the intermediate results. Binding a local variable is pretty cheap, so after a couple of calculations, it will come out faster.

In the special cases where only constants are used, the peephole optimiser can reduce those to constants

eg.

```
$ python3.3
Python 3.3.0 (default, Sep 29 2012, 17:17:45) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def x():
...     50*(50*12-1)
...     50*(50*12-1) * 100 + 10
...     50*(50*12-1) / 100 + 20
... 
>>> dis.dis(x)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               9 (29950) 
              3 POP_TOP              

  3           4 LOAD_CONST              14 (2995010) 
              7 POP_TOP              

  4           8 LOAD_CONST              19 (319.5) 
             11 POP_TOP              
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

If in doubt, prefer the readable version. Micro optimise if you really need those extra microseconds

Answer (score 0):

The literal will be faster simply because it doesn't have to refer to anything.  There is no preprocessing in Python, so you can't do a #define like in C.

Comment: but wouldn't it recalculate the expression 50*(50*12-1) every time?

Comment: You know what, I do believe I actually preprocessed it in my head, such that each occurrance of 50*(50*12-1) was, in my imagination, 29950.  :)